# MySQL Count All Rows and Count All Rows Where field1 = 1

Tags: mysql, count

How can I count all rows where game_id = 1 and count all rows where userid = 2 has hit = 1 on that game_id (1)

```
id    userid  game_id    hit    score    date
1     2       1          1      1        null
2     2       1          0      2        null
3     2       1          1      3        null
4     4       1          1      1        null
5     2       1          1      4        null
6     2       1          0      5        null
7     2       2          1      1        null
```

and more rows

For above db information
We should have

6 rows for the game_id = 1
and 3 for userid  = 2 and hit = 1

The result returned back should be 6, 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `CASE` expression.

If you want each count in different columns, use the below sql query.

**Query**

```
select 
    count(case game_id when 1 then 1 end) as count1,
    count(case when game_id = 1 and userid = 2 and hit = 1 then 1 end) as count2
from tblGame;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+--------+
| count1 | count2 |
+--------+--------+
|      6 |      3 |
+--------+--------+
```

else if you want combine the counts with a comma then use `CONCAT` in the query.

**Query**

```
select concat(t.count1,', ',t.count2) as `count` from
(
  select 
      count(case game_id when 1 then 1 end) as count1,
      count(case when game_id = 1 and userid = 2 and hit = 1 then 1 end) as count2
  from tblGame
)t;
```

**Output**

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|  6, 3 |
+-------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66277/1)

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `count`

```
select (select count(*) from table where where game_id = 1) as count1,
(select count(*) from table where userid = 2 and hit = 1) as count2
 from table limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this MySQL query :-

```
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_table WHERE game_id = 1` 
and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_table 
WHERE userid = 2 AND hit = 1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this MySQL query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(userid) as totalusers, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ForgeRock 
where game_id = 1 ) as totalgame FROM ForgeRock where game_id = 1 and
userid = 2 and hit = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebf386/12/0)